# least value of $f(x,y) = 2x^2+y^2+2xy+2x-3y+8\;,$ Where $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The least value of $f(x,y) = 2x^2+y^2+2xy+2x-3y+8\;,$ Where $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $$K = 2x^2+y^2+2xy+2x-3y+8$$

So $$\displaystyle y^2+(2x-3)y+2x^2+2x+8-K=0$$

Now For real values of $y\;,$ We have $\bf{Discriminant\geq 0}$

So $$(2x-3)^2-4(2x^2+2x+8-K)\geq 0$$

So $$-4x^2-20x-23+4K\geq0\Rightarrow 4x^2+20x+23-4K\leq0$$

Now How can I Solve after that, Help me

Thanks

Comment: With the precalc tag, do you mean to indicate that you specifically do not want a solution that uses calculus?

Comment: No It does not mean that we can not use calculus, If you have a solution using calculus Then you can post it., Thanks

Comment: @juantheron Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
&2x^2+y^2+2xy+2x-3y+8\\
&=\left(x^2+y^2+\frac94+2xy-3x-3y\right)+x^2+5x+\frac{23}{4}\\
&=(x+y-3/2)^2+x^2+5x+\frac{23}4\\
&=(x+y-3/2)^2+\left(x+\frac52\right)^2-\frac12\\
&\geq-\frac12\\
&(x=-\frac52,\space y=4)
\end{align}

Answer (score 5):

You have
$$4x^2+20x+23-4K\le 0.$$
So, 
$$\begin{align}K&\ge x^2+5x+\frac{23}{4}\\&=\left(x+\frac 52\right)^2-\frac 12\\&\ge -\frac 12\end{align}$$
The equality is attained when $x=-\frac 52,y=4$.

Comment: Very Nice Mathlove. I did not Noticed that, Thanks for Nice Solution.

Comment: To Mathlove can we solve it Using Completing square method.

Comment: @juantheron: Sure. Just try it:)

Answer (score 1):

since it has calculus tag im going to try solve it with calculus

heres my try:

we are going to find some extreme point and then check it if its minimum or maximum

let $Z = 2x^2 +y^2 +2xy + 2x -3y +8 $

so we got $\frac{dz}{dx} =  4x + 2y +2 $ and $\frac{dz}{dx} =  2y +2x -3 $

now we are going to find a possible extreme point from the equation above

$ 4x + 2y + 2 = 0 $ change this to $ 4x+2y = -2$

$2x + 2y - 3 = 0 $ change this to  $ 2x + 2y = 3$

by eliminate 2 of the equation above we got x = $\frac{-5}{2}$ and y = $4$

and now we are going to check if this point is minimum or maximum .

by using second derivation $\frac{d^2z}{dx^2} = 4 $

now by subtitute $(x,y) = (\frac{-5}{2} ,4 )$ to the $\frac{d^2z}{dx^2} = 4 $

we got $\frac{d^2z}{dx^2} > 0 $, since $\frac{d^2z}{dx^2} > 0  $ this mean (x,y)

is a extreme minimum . this mean by subtituting $(x,y) = (\frac{-5}{2} ,4 )$ we 
 are going to get a minimum result